# How to post an image to this web service

Tags: php, laravel, file, guzzle

http://labelary.com/viewer.html

This webservice has an 'undocumented' service where you can post them a png, and then send you back the image encoded as a zpl file (for label printers). [don't worry, I'm not trying to do anything they don't want me to do, it's mentioned at the bottom here that they allow this undocumented use of their api](http://labelary.com/faq.html#image-conversion)

So, when you use the api from within the web portal, it makes a post request to this url: `http://api.labelary.com/v1/graphics`

If I upload a png and then look in the Network tab of Chrome developer tools, I can see that it posted a Form Data, `file: (binary)`

In their documentation, they actually recommend this Ruby library: https://github.com/rjocoleman/labelary -- this has implemented into it a way to send the post request with the file up to that url and get the zpl data back.

If you navigate to [labelary/lib/labelary/image.rb](https://github.com/rjocoleman/labelary/blob/master/lib/labelary/image.rb) you can see the code for the `encode` function:

```
    def encode
      response = Labelary::Client.connection.post '/v1/graphics', { file: @file }, { Accept: 'application/json' }
      image = response.body

      return '^GFA,' + image['totalBytes'].to_s + ',' + image['totalBytes'].to_s + ',' + image['rowBytes'].to_s + ',' + image['data'] + '^FS'
    end
```

It makes that request using the `faraday` request library, if that's of any relevance.

**So basically, I'm trying to implement this request in php+laravel using Guzzle.** Now I know how to make a post request, but I don't exactly know how to send an image, and I searched around and came up with this code, which isn't working:

```
        $pngPath = storage_path('image.png'); // this is a confirmed real file on my system in the storage folder
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $response = $client->request('POST', 'http://api.labelary.com/v1/graphics', [
            'headers' => [
                'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data'
            ],
            'multipart' => [
                [
                    'name'     => 'file',
                    'contents' => fopen($pngPath, 'r'),
                ]
            ]
        ]);
```

When I make that request, I get this error message that doesn't have much detail: `ERROR: HTTP 400 Bad Request`

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to modify a bit of my request and it worked -- I think it might have been the Content-Type header messing me up more than anything.

This is what the request looks like now:

```
            $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
            $response = $client->request('POST', 'http://api.labelary.com/v1/graphics', [
                'headers' => [
                    // 'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data'
                    'Accept' => 'application/json'
                ],
                'multipart' => [
                    [
                        'Content-Type' => 'image/png',
                        'name'     => 'file',
                        'contents' => fopen($pngPath, 'r'),
                        'filename' => basename($pngPath)
                    ]
                ]
            ]);
```

Sorry for wasting everyone's time!